# How to get row rank in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I'm querying objects in the database and was wondering how do I get the rank order of which it occurred. So I have something like:

```
var productRank = db.Products.OrderBy(i => i.WilsonScore);
```

So I want to take a list of products, order then by their score and get the row number of the product ID I choose. So let's say I get

```
ProductID|Score
12 0.99
23 0.95
34 0.93
```

I want to get the product who has an ID of 34 row number of the returned result. In this case, it would be 3. If I chose ID 12, it would be 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the index using Select...

```
var productRanks = db.Products.OrderByDescending(i => i.WilsonScore)
                       .Select((p, idx) => new { Rank = idx + 1, Product = p });

var product34Rank = productRanks
                       .Single(p => p.Product.ProductID == 34)
                       .Rank;  // 3
```

Comment: I'm getting an exception "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType9`3[System.Int64,System.Int32,System.Int32]] Select[<>f__AnonymousType8`2,<>f__AnonymousType9`3](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType8`2[System.Int64,System.Int32]], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[<>f__AnonymousType8`2[System.Int64,System.Int32],System.Int32,<>f__AnonymousType9`3[System.Int64,System.Int32,System.Int32]]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: Same here. This overload of select only works in memory but EF cannot translate it to sql...

Comment: But this is indexing not a Rank. What will be rank of this link 10,20,20,30,40  : e.g. 1:40,2:30,3:20,3:20,4:10